# WP - Links unclickable IE8 in widget area

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-8, clickable

I've got links in the simple text widget in my wordpress site. No problem with any browser, except IE8 ( which MUST be massively used in my 1940 company's computer bay ).

I searched. Lot. Can't figure why IE doesn't see it.

Here is the code of the page. It is long. You can find the page there: [santemonteregie.net/connivence](http://santemonteregie.net/connivence)

Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="fr-FR">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="fr-FR">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="fr-FR">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>V-6 No-18 | 16 juin 2014 | Connivence - Le Webzine de la Montérégie</title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/xmlrpc.php">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/style-ie.css">
    <script src="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Connivence - Le Webzine de la Montérégie &raquo; Flux" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Connivence - Le Webzine de la Montérégie &raquo; Flux des commentaires" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Connivence - Le Webzine de la Montérégie &raquo; Flux de la catégorie V-6 No-18 | 16 juin 2014" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/category/16juin2014/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css'  href='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-style-css'  href='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/themes/twentythirteenchild/style.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-ie-css'  href='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/css/ie.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9.1" />
    <style type="text/css" id="twentythirteen-header-css">
            .site-header {
            background: url(http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/cropped-header6.jpg) no-repeat scroll top;
            background-size: 1600px auto;
        }
            .site-title,
        .site-description {
            position: absolute;
            clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        }
        </style>
    </head>

<body class="archive category category-16juin2014 category-12 single-author sidebar">

        <div style="width:100%; max-width:1600px; min-width:300px;">        <a href="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/"><img src="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/header-principal.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;"></a>     </div>
        <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="background-size:auto auto;">


            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Aller au contenu principal">Aller au contenu principal</a>
                    <div class="menu-menu1-container"><ul id="menu-menu1" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-123"><a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/category/16juin2014/">Édition courante</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117"><a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/archives/">Archives</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-213" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-213"><a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/inscription/">Abonnez-vous</a></li>
</ul></div>                 <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Recherche pour&nbsp;:</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Recherche&hellip;" value="" name="s" title="Recherche pour&nbsp;:" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Rechercher" />
            </form>             </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main">
<style type="text/css" media="all"> 
            .wp-caption-text{
                display: none;
            }
</style>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

                    <header>
                <center><h2 ><p>Volume 6, numéro 18 &#8211; 16 juin 2014</p>
</h2></center>
                <!--
                                <div class="archive-meta"></div>
                                -->
            </header><!-- .archive-header -->

                                    <!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->
    <div style="background-color:#e4e3f3;"> 

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-107" class="post-107 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-pdg category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                <img src="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/PDG3.png" style="width:100%; max-width:600;"><br>
                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/le-financement-du-reseau-monteregien-la-force-du-nous-2/" rel="bookmark">Le financement du réseau montérégien : la force du NOUS!</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Avant la pause estivale, il m’apparaît important de faire le point sur la situation financière de notre réseau. Nous sommes tous conscients de traverser une crise importante en matière de finances publiques et il ne faut pas être surpris des nouvelles compressions financières imposées à l’ensemble des ministères. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/le-financement-du-reseau-monteregien-la-force-du-nous-2/#more-107" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->

    </div>


<article><header class="entry-header"><h1 style="color:#eeb111;">Nouvelles</h1></header></article><!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-103" class="post-103 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/programme-pour-les-grands-utilisateurs-de-lurgence-au-csss-pierre-boucher/" rel="bookmark">Programme pour les grands utilisateurs de l’urgence au CSSS Pierre-Boucher</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

<!-- Here I took some article off the code to make it shorter -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Le 5 juin dernier avait lieu la 2e édition du colloque en santé mentale sous le thème « Des idées plein la tête ». Le colloque qui s’est déroulé au Collège de Valleyfield a réuni près de 150 participants issus de tous les milieux (communautaire, institutionnel, municipal, etc.). <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/succes-de-la-deuxieme-edition-du-colloque-en-sante-mentale-dans-le-suroit/#more-86" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-81" class="post-81 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/des-jeunes-de-linlb-participent-a-un-programme-pour-faciliter-les-choix-de-carriere/" rel="bookmark">Des jeunes de l’INLB participent à un programme pour faciliter les choix de carrière</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Montréal Relève a accepté d’intégrer les jeunes de l’Institut Nazareth et Louis-Braille (INLB) au <a style="color: #525252;" href="http://www.projetclassesaffaires.ca/">Programme classes affaires</a>.</p>
<p style="color: #333333;"></p>
<p style="color: #333333;"> <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/des-jeunes-de-linlb-participent-a-un-programme-pour-faciliter-les-choix-de-carriere/#more-81" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-79" class="post-79 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/une-integration-a-la-maternelle-plus-facile-grace-a-linlb/" rel="bookmark">Une intégration à la maternelle plus facile grâce à l’INLB</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Afin de favoriser une entrée harmonieuse à la maternelle, le Programme enfance-jeunesse propose un groupe de préparation à l&rsquo;intégration scolaire, pour les enfants fonctionnellement voyants, ainsi que leurs parents. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/une-integration-a-la-maternelle-plus-facile-grace-a-linlb/#more-79" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-76" class="post-76 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/certificat-de-conformite-de-loffice-quebecois-de-la-langue-francaise-delivre-au-crdited-srsor/" rel="bookmark">Certificat de conformité de l’Office québécois de la langue française délivré au CRDITED SRSOR</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;"></p>
<p style="color: #333333;">C&rsquo;est avec une grande fierté que le CRDITED Les Services de Réadaptation du Sud-Ouest et du Renfort a reçu le certificat de conformité de l&rsquo;Office québécois de la langue française. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/certificat-de-conformite-de-loffice-quebecois-de-la-langue-francaise-delivre-au-crdited-srsor/#more-76" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-73" class="post-73 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/la-journee-mondiale-de-lutte-contre-la-maltraitance-envers-les-personnes-ainees-soulignee-en-monteregie/" rel="bookmark">La journée mondiale de lutte contre la maltraitance envers les personnes aînées soulignée en Montérégie</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p class="wp-caption-text">Source : http//:maltraitanceaines.gouv.qc.ca</p>
<p style="color: #333333;">Des travailleurs œuvrant dans les établissements de santé et de services sociaux, au sein des corps policiers, de groupes communautaires et d’associations d’aînés ont porté le ruban mauve le 15 juin dernier afin de dénoncer la maltraitance envers les aînés  <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/la-journee-mondiale-de-lutte-contre-la-maltraitance-envers-les-personnes-ainees-soulignee-en-monteregie/#more-73" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-71" class="post-71 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/une-route-sans-fin-au-centre-jeunesse-de-la-monteregie-10-ans-deja/" rel="bookmark">Une route sans fin au Centre jeunesse de la Montérégie : 10 ans déjà!</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Le 1er juin dernier, c’est sous un soleil rayonnant que plus de 250 jeunes et intervenants du Centre jeunesse de la Montérégie ont participé à la 10e édition d’Une route sans fin. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/une-route-sans-fin-au-centre-jeunesse-de-la-monteregie-10-ans-deja/#more-71" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->



<!-- Début des background selon les catégories -->

<!-- Fin des background selon les catégories -->

<article id="post-68" class="post-68 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-16juin2014">
    <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title">

        <!-- Début des en-têtes de catégories -->

                        <!-- Fin des en-têtes de catégories -->

        <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/bonnes-vacances/" rel="bookmark">Bonnes vacances!</a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
                                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
                <p style="color: #333333;">Connivence fait relâche pour la période estivale. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/bonnes-vacances/#more-68" class="more-link">Lire la suite →</a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">

            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->

<!-- Fermeture de la div pour les background de catégories -->






        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <div id="tertiary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
        <div class="sidebar-inner">
            <div class="widget-area">
                <aside id="text-13" class="widget widget_text">         <div class="textwidget"><div style="z-index:100000000;" class="widget2"> <img src="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/evenements.png"></center><ul class="display-posts-listing"><li class="listing-item"><a class="title" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/visite-guidee-des-fermes-de-la-monteregie/"><span style="z-index:1000;">Visite guidée des fermes de la Montérégie<br><p>Une journée spéciale dédiée aux fermes montérégiennes a été organisée pas l&rsquo;Agence de la santé et des services sociaux de la Montérégie. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/visite-guidee-des-fermes-de-la-monteregie/#more-196" class="more-link">Lire la suite -></a></p>
</span></a></li><li class="listing-item"><a class="title" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/colloque-drmg2014/"><span style="z-index:1000;">Colloque DRMG 2014<br><p>Le colloque DRMG 2014 aura lieu, encore une fois, dans une foule de gens très intéressés. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/colloque-drmg2014/#more-194" class="more-link">Lire la suite -></a></p>
</span></a></li></ul></div></div>
        </aside><aside id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">         <div class="textwidget"><div style="z-index:100000000;" class="widget2"> <img src="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/BP-widget.png"></center><ul class="display-posts-listing"><li class="listing-item"><a class="title" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/les-tiques/"><span style="z-index:1000;">Les tiques !<br><p>Il est généralement important de garder les tiques lorsque nous les trouvons. Par contre, pour des raisons hors de notre contrôle ( sic), la procédure ne peut pas être faite correctement. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/les-tiques/#more-203" class="more-link">Lire la suite -></a></p>
</span></a></li></ul></div></div>
        </aside><aside id="text-11" class="widget widget_text">         <div class="textwidget"><div style="z-index:100000000;" class="widget2"> <img src="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/PR-widget.png"></center><ul class="display-posts-listing"><li class="listing-item"><a class="title" href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/grand-projet-514-450/"><span style="z-index:1000;">Grand projet 514-450<br><p>Comme vous le savez peut-être, le grand projet 514-450 bat son plein en ce moment. <a href="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/grand-projet-514-450/#more-217" class="more-link">Lire la suite -></a></p>
</span></a></li></ul></div></div>
        </aside><aside id="text-10" class="widget widget_text">         <div class="textwidget"><div class="widget2">
<img src="http://www.santemonteregie.net/connivence/images/COMM-widget.png">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Nom</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="18"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Courriel</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="18"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Message</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="18" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Envoyer"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></div>
        </aside>            </div><!-- .widget-area -->
        </div><!-- .sidebar-inner -->
    </div><!-- #tertiary -->

        </div><!-- #main -->
        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
                <div id="secondary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
        <div class="widget-area">
            <aside id="newsletterwidget-2" class="widget widget_newsletterwidget"><h3 class="widget-title">Abonnez-vous à Connivence</h3>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof newsletter_check !== "function") {
window.newsletter_check = function (f) {
    var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+$/;
    if (!re.test(f.elements["ne"].value)) {
        alert("Le courriel n\'est pas valide");
        return false;
    }
    if (f.elements["nn"] && (f.elements["nn"].value == "" || f.elements["nn"].value == f.elements["nn"].defaultValue)) {
        alert("Le nom n\'es pas valide");
        return false;
    }
    if (f.elements["ny"] && !f.elements["ny"].checked) {
        alert("Vous devez accepter les règlements de confidentialité");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
//]]>
</script>

<div class="newsletter newsletter-widget">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof newsletter_check !== "function") {
window.newsletter_check = function (f) {
    var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+$/;
    if (!re.test(f.elements["ne"].value)) {
        alert("Le courriel n\'est pas valide");
        return false;
    }
    if (f.elements["nn"] && (f.elements["nn"].value == "" || f.elements["nn"].value == f.elements["nn"].defaultValue)) {
        alert("Le nom n\'es pas valide");
        return false;
    }
    if (f.elements["ny"] && !f.elements["ny"].checked) {
        alert("Vous devez accepter les règlements de confidentialité");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
//]]>
</script>

<form action="http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/do/subscribe.php" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="nr" value="widget"/><p><input class="newsletter-firstname" type="text" name="nn" value="Nom" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p><p><input class="newsletter-email" type="email" required name="ne" value="Courriel" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p><p><input class="newsletter-profile newsletter-profile-1" type="text" name="np1" value="Établissement" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p><p><input class="newsletter-profile newsletter-profile-2" type="text" name="np2" value="Fonction" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p><p><input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer"/></p></form></div></aside><aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text"><h3 class="widget-title">À propos de Connivence</h3>          <div class="textwidget"><p>Connivence paraît tous les deux lundis<br />
Tombée : le mardi précédant la parution</p>
<p>Suggestion de sujets ou commentaires : chantal.vallee.agence16@ssss.gouv.qc.ca </p>
<p>Toute reproduction des textes est encouragée à condition de mentionner la source. </p>
</div>
        </aside><aside id="text-8" class="widget widget_text">          <div class="textwidget"><p><br><br />
Éditeur : Agence de la santé et des services sociaux de la Montérégie<br />
Rédactrice en chef : Christine Daniel<br />
Coordonnatrice à la rédaction : Chantal Vallée<br />
Correction des textes : Lynn Provost</p>
</div>
        </aside>        </div><!-- .widget-area -->
    </div><!-- #secondary -->

            <div class="site-info">
                                <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Plate-forme de publication personnelle à la pointe de la sémantique">Fièrement propulsé par WordPress</a>
            </div><!-- .site-info -->
        </footer><!-- #colophon -->
    </div><!-- #page -->

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://santemonteregie.net/connivence/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/functions.js?ver=2013-07-18'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if there was a working version of you're site to debug. No one likes to narrow down such a problem by reading through a big wall of code.

Comment: There is. Read my post. I pointed to the working page.

Comment: Anyways, I had to do it faster than I thought, so I just wasted all my css file, and started from scratch, and now it works.

Still, I don't understand why it didn't work ( well, I understand IE8 is just plain bad, but... ).

I think it had something to do with the position of divs. If I put a span position absolute inside my text div, the link would work, but the layout would be all messed up.

Anyways, thanks for your time..

Comment: How do I mark this as answered ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Glad that you solved it. You have to write an answer to your own question, then you can mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll do that.